# How to set the maximum image height in lightning:carousel?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

We are using the `lightning:carousel` component to show some files uploaded via a custom component. However, some of the images are very large and may be 1,000 or so pixels high. This has the affect of taking up the entire screen.

Is there a way to limit the height to around 500px or so, while keeping the aspect ration intact? We tried to see the hight like so, but it stretches the image:

```
.THIS img {
    max-height: 400px;
}
```

`lightning:carousel` does not appear to have any properties to scale the image. Has anyone been able to solve this problem and if so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> object-fit: contain;
> ```

prevents image streching.